# Issue with angular.element using counter of elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing an application using AngularJS. In some part of my application, I have a button, when I click that button it adds a new input to add telephone. With each input, there is a remove link to delete that input.

With my code, I am using counter.

For some reasons, I am not able to get it right!!

View:

```
<div id="div{{$index}}" style='z-index: 1' ng-repeat="cEdit in telephone" ng-show="contactsElements">
    <input type="text" ng-model="cEdit" maxlength="15">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="removeDIV($index)">Remove</a>
</div>
<div ng-show="contactsElements">
    <div id="space-for-new-telephones"></div>
    <button ng-click="addDIV()">Add</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.removeDIV = function (arrAddr) {
    console.log("Array Index = " + arrAddr);
    var iEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#div' + arrAddr));
    iEl.remove();
    if ($scope.count > 0) {
        $scope.count = $scope.count - 1;
        console.log($scope.count);
    }                
}

$scope.addDIV = function () {
    if ($scope.count <= 2) {
        angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-new-telephones')).append("<div id='div" + $scope.count + "'><input type='text' ng-model='$scope.telephone.num[" + $scope.count + "]' maxlength='15'>&nbsp;<a href='javascript:void(0)' ng-click='removeDIV(" + $scope.count + ")'>Remove</a></div>");
        $scope.count++;
        console.log($scope.count);
    }        
}
```

My problem is with the input that I manually add them by pressing the button... It looks like I have a problem with the append command.

```
ng-click='removeDIV(" + $scope.count + ")'
```

I am able to add the element and display it in the view, but cannot remove it later.

Please note that the element that already in the view using ng-repeat are working properly and I am able to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Not tried running your code but I think the following code will solve your problem

```
    var html = "<div id='div" + $scope.count 
      + "'><input type='text' ng-model='$scope.telephone.num[" 
      + $scope.count + "]' maxlength='15'>&nbsp;"
      +"<a href='javascript:void(0)' ng-click='removeDIV(" 
      + $scope.count + ")'>Remove</a></div>"

    angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-new-telephones'))
    .append($compile(html)($scope));
```

Comment: What is the differences? It is the same as my code. Additionally, this code will not work unless I use directive.

Comment: I think if you add $compile as dependency it will work on controller

Comment: Thank you Abu Sufian, I will try this and I will get back to you if it works

Comment: But janko's idea is much better

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't manipulate the DOM like that with angular. You should manipulate data in your code, and have the DOM reflect those changes for you. Just like you are doing in the first div in your code with `ng-repeat="cEdit in telephone"`.
You can create an array in your `$scope` to hold all the new telephones. Then add and remove items from the array, using `ng-repeat` to render the existing items, instead of `append` and `remove`.

If you do need to manipulate the DOM, you should use directives - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Here is some further information about the DOM manipulation concept - http://tech.zumba.com/2014/08/02/angularjs-forget-jquery/

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand your point. I will try to change my code and then I will get back to you. I have only one question, once I change in the array in my $scope, how can I call the ng-repeat to render the new changes?

Comment: @AhmedAlsahli - You shouldn't need to. Angular watches for changes in the scope, and updates the DOM for you. That's the main reason you shouldn't do it with jQuery, as it is likely to conflict with angular. There are cases when angular doesn't know about scope changes (IE.: an asynchronous update). On those cases, you can use `$apply`, `$timeout` or `$digest`. More info here - https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `id="div{{$index}}"`s should be wrapped into
   `"space-for-new-telephones"`, or maybe you can just call it
   `"space-for-telephones"` or you can remove the wrapper.
2. You don't have to manipulate doms(view) when inserting a new telephone feild like `angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-new-telephones')).append("<div id='div" + $scope.count + "'><input type='text' ng-model='$scope.telephone.num[" + $scope.count + "]' maxlength='15'>&nbsp;<a href='javascript:void(0)' ng-click='removeDIV(" + $scope.count + ")'>Remove</a></div>");`. Just modify the model and the "view" will change accordingly.`$scope.telephones.push("");`
3. The same as 2, removing a telephone field should also be realised by manipulating the model: `$scope.telephone.splice(arrAddr,1);`
4. Use `track by` to avoid error reporting when you have duplicate telephone numbers, and use `ng-model="telephone[$index]"` to synchronise between inputs and models on $scope immediately.

So the codes should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="teleApp" ng-controller="tele">
    <div id="div{{$index}}" style='z-index: 1' ng-repeat="cEdit in telephone track by $index" ng-show="contactsElements">
        <input type="text" ng-model="telephone[$index]" maxlength="15">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="removeDIV($index)">Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="contactsElements">
        <button ng-click="addDIV()">Add</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS codes:

```
var teleApp = angular.module("teleApp", []);
teleApp.controller("tele",function($scope){
    $scope.contactsElements = true;
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.telephone = [
    ]

    $scope.removeDIV = function (arrAddr) {
        console.log("Array Index = " + arrAddr);
        $scope.telephone.splice(arrAddr,1);
        if ($scope.count > 0) {
            $scope.count = $scope.count - 1;
            console.log($scope.count);
        }
    }

    $scope.addDIV = function () {
        if ($scope.count <= 2) {
            $scope.telephone.push('');
            $scope.count++;
            console.log($scope.count);
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style='z-index: 1' ng-repeat="cEdit in telephone" ng-show="contactsElements">
<input type="text" ng-model="phone.number" maxlength="15">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="remove(telephone, $index)">Remove</a> 
</div>
<div ng-show="contactsElements">
<div id="space-for-new-telephones"></div>
<button ng-click="add(telephone, phone)">Add</button>                                                
</div>


$scope.remove = function (telephone, $index) {
    delete telephone[$index];
}

$scope.add= function (telephone, phone) {
   telephone.push(phone)
}
```

You have bad idea about how angular works

EDIT: 

Well, I recomend You to take a look at this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/premaseem/u4obssd3/1/)
there is all You want to know. 
Sentence You present is working, but wrong answer my friend!

I recomend, to not use splice as removal from array, becouse there is a problem with reindexing.

Imagine that You push a delete button, and item with index 0 is removed when  $http request was resolved. And all is good as You do it once! 

When You hit this button 3 times and all these resolve will be waiting for resolve, there is thread that wrong item will be removed

And now I hope You will appreciate this exaple of approche with splice
on specially edited by my for You [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxee2fxj/)

the thing is press second button 3 times quickly and take a look what just happened.

I got a lot of exp in angular. Dont blame me for telling truth my friend, hope You got this lesson

Comment: It would be better to write your recommendation instead of telling me that I have bad ideas about how it works! I am new to Angular and I am still learning. So, what about you explain so we can learn from you

Comment: And by the way, delete does not delete an item from array! `$scope.telephone.splice($index, 1);` is the right sentence. Thanks